# Validate phone number with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I found this code in some website, and it works perfectly. It validates that the phone number is in one of these formats:
**(123) 456-7890** or **123-456-7890**

The problem is that my client (I don't know why, maybe client stuffs) wants to add another format, the ten numbers consecutively, something like this: **1234567890**.

I'm using this regular expression,

```
/^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/
```

How can I add that it also validates the another format? I'm not good with regular expressions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: As a rule of thumb — trying to validate phone numbers is doomed to failure. What with different structures in different countries and extensions, its a very difficult problem.

Comment: And what about e.g. the French notation? "12 34 56 78 90" Simply remove everything except numbers (except maybe a plus sign at the beginning) and check the length.

Comment: You *shouldn't*, in fact, use regular expressions to [validate phone numbers properly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4338544/1269037).

Answer (score 156, accepted):

First off, your format validator is obviously only appropriate for [NANP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan) (country code +1) numbers.  Will your application be used by someone with a phone number from outside North America?  If so, you don't want to prevent those people from entering a perfectly valid [international] number.

Secondly, your validation is incorrect.  NANP numbers take the form `NXX NXX XXXX` where `N` is a digit 2-9 and `X` is a digit 0-9.  Additionally, area codes and exchanges may not take the form `N11` (end with two ones) to avoid confusion with special services *except* numbers in a non-geographic area code (800, 888, 877, 866, 855, 900) may have a `N11` exchange.

So, your regex will pass the number (123) 123 4566 even though that is not a valid phone number.  You can fix that by replacing `\d{3}` with `[2-9]{1}\d{2}`.

Finally, I get the feeling you're validating user input in a web browser.  Remember that client-side validation is [only a **convenience** you provide to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726617/form-validation-with-javascript-vs-php); you still need to validate all input (again) on the server.

**TL;DR** don't use a regular expression to [validate complex real-world data like phone numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5059082/1269037) or [URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links/21925491#21925491). Use a [specialized library](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber).

Comment: I agree that regex is not sufficient to validate phone numbers because the phone numbering plan actually works based on range, e.g. 12300000 to 12399999 (http://www.numberingplans.com/?page=plans&sub=phonenr&alpha_2_input=US&current_page=15242)

Comment: The problem is that it takes >500Kb to bundle libphonenumber in your frontend app. (https://bundlephobia.com/package/google-libphonenumber@3.2.22)

I think it's a good starting point if you want to jump in phone number validation: https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md

Given the complexity I would also consider to use specialized online services, eg: https://validatephonenumber.com/

Answer (score 255):

My regex of choice is:

```
/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im
```

Valid formats:

**(123) 456-7890**
**(123)456-7890**
**123-456-7890**
**123.456.7890**
**1234567890**
**+31636363634**
**075-63546725**

Comment: What is /im ?
Can't find the explanation on google :)

Comment: @SarinSuriyakoon `i` makes the expression case-insensitive and `m` performs multi-line searches

Comment: why would you need case-insensitive for numbers?

Comment: This regex is great because if you remove the `^` at the beginning and `$` the end it can find phone numbers in the middle of strings as well

Comment: this regex dont works for me, 123456789 returns false

Comment: @darioxlz '123456789' is not a valid length for a phone number

Comment: Does not handle +1 (415)-555-1212, and it should.

Comment: linted version `/^\+?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4,6}$/im`

Comment: This had some redundant escaping in it so I modified it `/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im`

Comment: how can I apply in javascript? I used this code but it is not working.

 function keyispressed(event) {

            const REGEXP = /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im;

            if (!REGEXP.test(event.key)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            
        }

Comment: Cannot validate 85021622, 0776127374 like numbers

Comment: @punjabi4life 123456789 is valid phone number length i.e. in Czech Republic.

Answer (score 82):

If you are looking for 10 and only 10 digits, ignore everything but the digits-

```
   return value.match(/\d/g).length===10;
```

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest. Easy breezy. And too much validation can be a bad thing anyway.

Comment: This is the best way to go. Unless you REALLY care what format it is in, all this does is make sure the number is partially valid, and not a bunch of jibberish.

Comment: You mean match(/\d/g) not match(/\d/) or the length will be 1, not 10; also, the match on an empty string is null. At the very least it should be var m = value.match(/\d/g); return m && m.length === 10

Comment: Or `return (value.match(/\d/g) || []).length == 10` or the much simpler (but equally flawed): `return value.replace(/\D/g,'').length == 10`.

Comment: I like this one: `/\D/gi.test(value)`. Everything that's not a digit, including whitespaces, dashes, etc...

Answer (score 52):

```
/^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$/g
```

> (123) 456-7890
>   +(123) 456-7890
>   +(123)-456-7890
>   +(123) - 456-7890
>   +(123) - 456-78-90
>   123-456-7890
>   123.456.7890
>   1234567890
>   +31636363634
>   075-63546725

This is a very loose option and I prefer to keep it this way, mostly I use it in registration forms where the users need to add their phone number.
Usually users have trouble with forms that enforce strict formatting rules, I prefer user to fill in the number and the format it in the display or before saving it to the database.
http://regexr.com/3c53v

Comment: regex slightly modified to allow e.g. for `+41 (79) 123 45 67` (Switzerland): `/^[+]?[\s./0-9]*[(]?[0-9]{1,4}[)]?[-\s./0-9]*$/g`

Comment: This one seems to be a good fit for me since it's not too string and seems to cover all of the international formats (and thanks @RemigiusStalder for the Switzerland fix)

Comment: If you have a java backend, you can add phone number normalization, e.g. from https://github.com/google/libphonenumber

Comment: Would be better to add character limit. Change the last * (asterisk) with [8, 14]: `/^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]{8,14}$/g`

Answer (score 36):

What I would do is ignore the format and validate the numeric content:

```
var originalPhoneNumber = "415-555-1212";

function isValid(p) {
  var phoneRe = /^[2-9]\d{2}[2-9]\d{2}\d{4}$/;
  var digits = p.replace(/\D/g, "");
  return phoneRe.test(digits);
}
```

Comment: Agree regarding ignoring formatting, .e.g. it's very common for mobile numbers to be presented with spaces like XXXX XXX XXX but for forms to require input without spaces, i.e. as XXXXXXXXXX.

Answer (score 33):

The following REGEX will validate any of these formats:

**(123) 456-7890

123-456-7890

123.456.7890

1234567890**

```
/^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/
```

Comment: You need to escape the `.` or else it will match an arbitrary character, breaking your regex.

Comment: This led me in the right direction. Thanks! Unfortunately this expression will also match (1234567890 and 123)4567890. ^((\([0-9]{3}\))|([0-9]{3}))[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4}$ takes care of that little problem.

Answer (score 25):

Where str could be any of these formarts:
555-555-5555
(555)555-5555
(555) 555-5555
555 555 5555
5555555555
1 555 555 5555

```js
function telephoneCheck(str) {
  var isphone = /^(1\s|1|)?((\(\d{3}\))|\d{3})(\-|\s)?(\d{3})(\-|\s)?(\d{4})$/.test(str);
  alert(isphone);
}
telephoneCheck("1 555 555 5555");
```

Comment: nice regexp, thats the best answer on this question

Answer (score 20):

I would suggest using something clearer (especially thinking to who will have to maintain the code)... what about:

```
var formats = "(999)999-9999|999-999-9999|9999999999";
var r = RegExp("^(" +
               formats
                 .replace(/([\(\)])/g, "\\$1")
                 .replace(/9/g,"\\d") +
               ")$");
```

where the regexp is built from a clear template ? Adding a new one would then be a no-brainer and may be even the customer itself could be able to do that in a "options" page.

Answer (score 11):

Try this one - it includes validation for international formats too.

`/^[+]?(1\-|1\s|1|\d{3}\-|\d{3}\s|)?((\(\d{3}\))|\d{3})(\-|\s)?(\d{3})(\-|\s)?(\d{4})$/g`

This regex validates the following format:

- (541) 754-3010  Domestic
- +1-541-754-3010  International
- 1-541-754-3010  Dialed in the US
- 001-541-754-3010  Dialed from Germany
- 191 541 754 3010  Dialed from France

Answer (score 10):

---

## Regex

Use the following Regex pattern:

```
/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im
```

Like this: `<input pattern="/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im">`*

---

## **Valid formats:**

(123) 456-7890,
(123)456-7890,
123-456-7890,
123.456.7890,
1234567890,
+31636363634 or
075-63546725

---

Answer (score 8):

This will work:

```
/^(()?\d{3}())?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)?\d{4}$/
```

The `?` character signifies that the preceding group should be matched zero or one times. The group `(-|\s)` will match either a `-` or a `|` character. Adding `?` after the second  occurrence of this group in your regex allows you to match a sequence of 10 consecutive digits.

Answer (score 8):

**try this**

```
/^(\+{0,})(\d{0,})([(]{1}\d{1,3}[)]{0,}){0,}(\s?\d+|\+\d{2,3}\s{1}\d+|\d+){1}[\s|-]?\d+([\s|-]?\d+){1,2}(\s){0,}$/gm
```

**valid formats**

- (123) 456-7890
- (123)456-7890
- 123-456-7890
- 1234567890
- +31636363634
- +3(123) 123-12-12
- +3(123)123-12-12
- +3(123)1231212
- +3(123) 12312123
- +3(123) 123 12 12
- 075-63546725
- +7910 120 54 54
- 910 120 54 54
- 8 999 999 99 99

https://regex101.com/r/QXAhGV/1

Comment: `{1}` is useless, `{0,}` is better written `*`. Why using all these capture groups? They slow down the process.

Comment: this is not good. because you can enter many numbers as you want.

Answer (score 7):

An actually simple way:

```
"9001234567".match(/^\d{10}$/g)
```

Answer (score 6):

`/^\+?1?\s*?\(?\d{3}(?:\)|[-|\s])?\s*?\d{3}[-|\s]?\d{4}$/`

Although this post is an old but want to leave my contribuition.
these are accepted:
5555555555
555-555-5555
(555)555-5555
1(555)555-5555
1 555 555 5555
1 555-555-5555
1 (555) 555-5555

these are not accepted:

555-5555 -> to accept this use:  `^\+?1?\s*?\(?(\d{3})?(?:\)|[-|\s])?\s*?\d{3}[-|\s]?\d{4}$`

5555555 -> to accept this use: `^\+?1?\s*?\(?(\d{3})?(?:\)|[-|\s])?\s*?\d{3}[-|\s]?\d{4}$`

1 555)555-5555
123**&!!asdf#
55555555
(6505552368)
2 (757) 622-7382
0 (757) 622-7382
-1 (757) 622-7382
2 757 622-7382
10 (757) 622-7382
27576227382
(275)76227382
2(757)6227382
2(757)622-7382
(555)5(55?)-5555

this is the code I used:

```
function telephoneCheck(str) {
  var patt = new RegExp(/^\+?1?\s*?\(?\d{3}(?:\)|[-|\s])?\s*?\d{3}[-|\s]?\d{4}$/);
  return patt.test(str);
}

telephoneCheck("+1 555-555-5555");
```

Comment: the only problem of this regex is that it considers valid a phone string with only one ')' or only one '(' (like "(555-555-5555")

Answer (score 3):

This reg ex is suitable for international phone numbers and multiple formats of mobile cell numbers.

Here is the regular expression:
/^(+{1}\d{2,3}\s?[(]{1}\d{1,3}[)]{1}\s?\d+|+\d{2,3}\s{1}\d+|\d+){1}[\s|-]?\d+([\s|-]?\d+){1,2}$/

Here is the JavaScript function

```
function isValidPhone(phoneNumber) {
    var found = phoneNumber.search(/^(\+{1}\d{2,3}\s?[(]{1}\d{1,3}[)]{1}\s?\d+|\+\d{2,3}\s{1}\d+|\d+){1}[\s|-]?\d+([\s|-]?\d+){1,2}$/);
    if(found > -1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This validates the following formats:

+44 07988-825 465 (with any combination of hyphens in place of space except that only a space must follow the +44)

+44 (0) 7988-825 465 (with any combination of hyphens in place of spaces except that no hyphen can exist directly before or after the (0) and the space before or after the (0) need not exist)

123 456-789 0123 (with any combination of hyphens in place of the spaces)

123-123 123 (with any combination of hyphens in place of the spaces)

123 123456 (Space can be replaced with a hyphen)

1234567890

No double spaces or double hyphens can exist for all formats.

Comment: This validates 123 as valid

Comment: @Fanky That's correct. Many countries uses short numbers like 560 for SMS voting in TV shows or for services payment.

Answer (score 3):

I took the one provided by @marty and modified it a little bit to accommodate more cases:

```
/^[\+]?([0-9][\s]?|[0-9]?)([(][0-9]{3}[)][\s]?|[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?)[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im
```

Valid formats:

1. +1 123 4567890
2. +11234567890
3. +1(123)4567890
4. +1(123)456-7890
5. +1 (123) 456-7890
6. +1 (123)456 7890
7. +1 123 456-7890
8. +1 123 456 7890
9. +1 123-456-7890
10. 123-456-7890
11. 123 456-7890
12. 123 456 7890
13. 123 4567890
14. 1234567890

Answer (score 2):

Everyone's answers are great, but here's one I think is a bit more comprehensive...

This is written for javascript match use of a single number in a single line:

```
^(?!.*911.*\d{4})((\+?1[\/ ]?)?(?![\(\. -]?555.*)\( ?[2-9][0-9]{2} ?\) ?|(\+?1[\.\/ -])?[2-9][0-9]{2}[\.\/ -]?)(?!555.?01..)([2-9][0-9]{2})[\.\/ -]?([0-9]{4})$
```

If you want to match at word boundaries, just change the ^ and $ to \b

I welcome any suggestions, corrections, or criticisms of this solution.  As far as I can tell, this matches the NANP format (for USA numbers - I didn't validate other North American countries when creating this), avoids any 911 errors (can't be in the area code or region code), eliminates only those 555 numbers which are actually invalid (region code of 555 followed by 01xx where x = any number).

Answer (score 2):

This function worked for us well:

```js
let isPhoneNumber = input => {

  try {
    let ISD_CODES = [93, 355, 213, 1684, 376, 244, 1264, 672, 1268, 54, 374, 297, 61, 43, 994, 1242, 973, 880, 1246, 375, 32, 501, 229, 1441, 975, 591, 387, 267, 55, 246, 1284, 673, 359, 226, 257, 855, 237, 1, 238, 1345, 236, 235, 56, 86, 61, 61, 57, 269, 682, 506, 385, 53, 599, 357, 420, 243, 45, 253, 1767, 1809, 1829, 1849, 670, 593, 20, 503, 240, 291, 372, 251, 500, 298, 679, 358, 33, 689, 241, 220, 995, 49, 233, 350, 30, 299, 1473, 1671, 502, 441481, 224, 245, 592, 509, 504, 852, 36, 354, 91, 62, 98, 964, 353, 441624, 972, 39, 225, 1876, 81, 441534, 962, 7, 254, 686, 383, 965, 996, 856, 371, 961, 266, 231, 218, 423, 370, 352, 853, 389, 261, 265, 60, 960, 223, 356, 692, 222, 230, 262, 52, 691, 373, 377, 976, 382, 1664, 212, 258, 95, 264, 674, 977, 31, 599, 687, 64, 505, 227, 234, 683, 850, 1670, 47, 968, 92, 680, 970, 507, 675, 595, 51, 63, 64, 48, 351, 1787, 1939, 974, 242, 262, 40, 7, 250, 590, 290, 1869, 1758, 590, 508, 1784, 685, 378, 239, 966, 221, 381, 248, 232, 65, 1721, 421, 386, 677, 252, 27, 82, 211, 34, 94, 249, 597, 47, 268, 46, 41, 963, 886, 992, 255, 66, 228, 690, 676, 1868, 216, 90, 993, 1649, 688, 1340, 256, 380, 971, 44, 1, 598, 998, 678, 379, 58, 84, 681, 212, 967, 260, 263],
      //extract numbers from string
      thenum = input.match(/[0-9]+/g).join(""),
      totalnums = thenum.length,
      last10Digits = parseInt(thenum) % 10000000000,
      ISDcode = thenum.substring(0, totalnums - 10);

    //phone numbers are generally of 8 to 16 digits
    if (totalnums >= 8 && totalnums <= 16) {
      if (ISDcode) {
        if (ISD_CODES.includes(parseInt(ISDcode))) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {}

  return false;
}

console.log(isPhoneNumber('91-9883208806'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Validate phone number + return formatted  data

```js
function validTel(str){
  str = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  var l = str.length;
  if(l<10) return ['error', 'Tel number length < 10'];
  
  var tel = '', num = str.substr(-7),
      code = str.substr(-10, 3),
      coCode = '';
  if(l>10) {
    coCode = '+' + str.substr(0, (l-10) );
  }
  tel = coCode +' ('+ code +') '+ num;
  
  return ['succes', tel];
}

console.log(validTel('+1 [223] 123.45.67'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this **regular expression**

```
/[^0-9+() -.]/g
```

Usage Example:

```
<input type="tel" id="txtUserMobile" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9+() -.]/g,'')">
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree that validating phone numbers is a difficult task.
As for this specific problem i would change the regex from

```
/^(()?\d{3}())?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/
```

to

```
/^(()?\d{3}())?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)?\d{4}$/
```

as the only one more element that becomes unnecessary is the last dash/space.

Comment: I'm really trying to up my Regex game! I'm checking your suggestion using "The Regex Coach." I'm using the regex (()?\d{3}())?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)?\d{4} and the target string (123) 456-7890 but for some reason it's only grabbing the last 7 digits. Any ideas?

Comment: Yep regex are a little rough on the brains... and patience. Ok try /^[(]?(\d{3})[)]?[-|\s]?(\d{3})[-|\s]?(\d{4})$/ the first part of the older regex didn't do well:  "(()?\d{3}())" (() the middle parenthesis was actually seen as part of the regex syntax and not characters to be looked for.

Answer (score 1):

`/^(()?\d{3}())?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)?\d{4}$/`

The `?` character signifies that the preceding group should be matched zero or one times. The group `(-|\s)` will match either a `-` or a `|` character.

Answer (score 1):

If you using on input tag than this code will help you. I write this code by myself and I think this is very good way to use in input. but you can change it using your format. It will help user to correct their format on input tag.

```
$("#phone").on('input', function() {  //this is use for every time input change.
        var inputValue = getInputValue(); //get value from input and make it usefull number
        var length = inputValue.length; //get lenth of input

        if (inputValue < 1000)
        {
            inputValue = '1('+inputValue;
        }else if (inputValue < 1000000) 
        {
            inputValue = '1('+ inputValue.substring(0, 3) + ')' + inputValue.substring(3, length);
        }else if (inputValue < 10000000000) 
        {
            inputValue = '1('+ inputValue.substring(0, 3) + ')' + inputValue.substring(3, 6) + '-' + inputValue.substring(6, length);
        }else
        {
            inputValue = '1('+ inputValue.substring(0, 3) + ')' + inputValue.substring(3, 6) + '-' + inputValue.substring(6, 10);
        }       
        $("#phone").val(inputValue); //correct value entered to your input.
        inputValue = getInputValue();//get value again, becuase it changed, this one using for changing color of input border
       if ((inputValue > 2000000000) && (inputValue < 9999999999))
      {
          $("#phone").css("border","black solid 1px");//if it is valid phone number than border will be black.
      }else
      {
          $("#phone").css("border","red solid 1px");//if it is invalid phone number than border will be red.
      }
  });

    function getInputValue() {
         var inputValue = $("#phone").val().replace(/\D/g,'');  //remove all non numeric character
        if (inputValue.charAt(0) == 1) // if first character is 1 than remove it.
        {
            var inputValue = inputValue.substring(1, inputValue.length);
        }
        return inputValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add a solution specifically for selecting non-local phone numbers(800 and 900 types).

```
(\+?1[-.(\s]?|\()?(900|8(0|4|5|6|7|8)\3+)[)\s]?[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this js function.
Returns true if it matches and false if it fails
[Ref](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phone-no-validation.php)

```js
function ValidatePhoneNumber(phone) {
        return /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/.test(phone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Regular expression: `/\b\d{3}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}\b/g`

Check out the format, hope it works :
    444-555-1234
    f:246.555.8888
    m:1235554567

Comment: Please format your answer (use four spaces as indents for a code block). An explanation to your code will also increase its quality.

Answer (score 0):

```
\\(?\d{3}\\)?([\-\s\.])?\d{3}\1?\d{4}
```

This will validate any phone number of variable format:

`\\(?\d{3}\\)?` finds 3 digits enclosed by parenthesis or not.

`([\-\s\.])?` finds any of these separator characters or not

`\d{3}` finds 3 digits

`\1` uses the first matched separator - this ensures that the separators are the same. So (000) 999-5555 will not validate here because there is a space and dash separator, so just remove the "\1" and replace with the separator sub-pattern (doing so will also validate  non standard formats). You should however be format hinting for user input anyway.

`\d{4}` finds 4 digits

Validates:

- (000) 999 5555
- (000)-999-5555
- (000).999.5555
- (000) 999-5555
- (000)9995555
- 000 999 5555
- 000-999-5555
- 000.999.5555
- 0009995555

BTW this is for JavaScript hence to double escapes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
/^[\+]?\d{2,}?[(]?\d{2,}[)]?[-\s\.]?\d{2,}?[-\s\.]?\d{2,}[-\s\.]?\d{0,9}$/im
```

valid formats:

1. (123) 456-7890
2. (123)456-7890
3. 123-456-7890
4. 123.456.7890
5. 1234567890
6. +31636363634
7. +3(123) 123-12-12
8. +3(123)123-12-12
9. +3(123)1231212
10. +3(123) 12312123
11. 075-63546725

Comment: Please make sure to include explanations with your answer. Although it may work, it is important to explain how and why in order to have complete and relevant information. Thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

A RegExp to Argentina´s numbers:
/^((+[0-9]{1,3}))?(([0-9]{8,13})|([0-9]{3,6})-([0-9]{4,7}))$/

Valids:

X: from 8 to 13 numbers

XXXXXXXX

separate numbers by a hyphen = X from 3 to 6; Y: from 4 to 7

XXXX-YYYY

Z: from 1 to 3

(+Z)XXXXXXXX

if you use Z then (+ ) is mandatory.

Answer (score -2):

Just ignore everything but digits.

Here is what I use:

```
// USA phones should contain at least 10 digits. Most EU country codes have only 9 digits, without leading 0 and country code prefix, eg [+380] 88 888-88-88.
// UPD. India: +91(+10 digits), China: +86(+ 10 OR 11 digits), etc.

stringProto.isValidPhone = function(minDigitsCount, maxDigitsCount) { // please customize minDigitsCount!
    var str = this.trim();
    if (str) {
        var len,
            isPlus = ("+" === str[0]),
            defMin = isPlus ? 11 : 10, // 10 digits is standard w/o country code for the US, Canada and many other countries. (...and 10-digits number is DEFAULT! AK: DON'T CHANGE IT HERE!)
                                    // however, for countries like Ukraine all numbers without country code have only 9 digits length, or even 7, without regional code.
                                    // So please customize minDigitsCount accordingly to the length of numbers in your default country!

            defMax = isPlus ? 14 : 11; // 11 digits maximum w/o country code (China) or 14 with country code (Austria).

        if ((str = str.match(/\d/g)) && (str = str.join(""))) { // all digits only!
            len = str.length;

            return len >= (minDigitsCount || defMin) &&
                   len <= (maxDigitsCount || defMax);
        }
    }
}
```