# RegularExpressionValidator for US phonenumber ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I am having an issue using the `RegularExpressionValidator` using Visual Studio 2010. This is my code:

```
<asp:Label ID="phone" runat="server" Text="Phone Number"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="phonebox"
    runat="server" TextMode="Phone"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Invalid Number" ControlToValidate="phonebox" 
    ValidationExpression="((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<br />
```

No matter what number I type in, I get an error message beside the field - even if I copy and paste a valid US phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_textbox_textmode.asp

Despite that enumeration on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textboxmode.aspx) you should use only this three:
SingleLine - Default. One line text box
MultiLine - Text box with multiple lines
Password - One line text box that masks the input

I suggest to leave it as simple text (default value) and use one of RegEx to verify correctness

```
<asp:TextBox ID="phonebox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="Invalid Number" ControlToValidate="phonebox"     ValidationExpression="((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Few others RegEx you can find at:
 [Regular expression to validate US phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776231/regular-expression-to-validate-us-phone-numbers)