# Mobile number model Regular Expression to validate mobile no greterthen 0 with fixed digit length 10 (MVC 5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

currently i am using code below, but not able to add validate > 0
currently its not validate 0000000000

```
[RegularExpression(@"(\b\d{3}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}\b)", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid mobile no.!")]
```

Comment: Unclear what your asking. Are your wanting `0000000000` to be invalid?

Comment: You can refer to the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904826/phone-number-validation-mvc

Comment: @StephenMuecke, i want to validate phone no greater then 0 with fixed digit length 10

Comment: @Bala, i have tried it but it also not working with validate > 0

Comment: Do you mean it must start with 1 - 9 - e.g. `100-000-0000` is valid but `000-000-0000` is not?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, i just want to validate 0000000000 is not a valid mobile number.

Comment: Yes, but what is? (you can replace the first `\d{3}` with `[1-9]\d{2}` so that `0000000000` is not valid)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks dear. its working. :)