# ASP.NET MVC Annotations - Email and Phone

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, annotations

I use the following model (part):

```
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber), Display(Name = "Phone #")]
public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber), Display(Name = "Fax #")]
public string FaxNo { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), Display(Name = "Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

and View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FaxNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FaxNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FaxNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

but when I try to type trash data (i.e. "blablabla"), Email field validator works, but phone validators are not. Why?

Comment: `[DataType]` is not a validation attribute, and if your claiming you get client side validation for `Email` its because your `EditorFor()` method generates `type="email"` and your getting HTML-5 validation, not `jquery` validation, and certainly not server side validation which must be implemented. What validation do you want for `PhoneNo`? (a regex?)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke what sense then in DataType at all?

Comment: Its an attribute used by the `EditorFor()` method to determine what type of form control to generate, e.g. `type="email"` or `type="number"` etc. For email validation, you use the `[EmailAddress]` attribute

Comment: Which type of Phone number you want to validate.can you provide some examples. user jquery validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataType` will Not give you any validation and show error messages. This is from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/SYSTEM.COMPONENTMODEL.DATAANNOTATIONS.DATATYPE.ASPX):

> The DataTypeAttribute attribute lets you mark fields by using a type that is more specific than the database intrinsic types. For example, a string data field that contains e-mail addresses can be attributed with the EmailAddress type. This information can be accessed by the field templates and modify how the data field is processed.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904826/phone-number-validation-mvc) answer for how to do phone number validation.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong attribute types.

If you inspect the source code for [DataTypeAttribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/DataTypeAttribute.cs) you will realize that it is primarily a base attribute used to create custom and targeted validation attribute.

The `DataTypeAttribute` in the original question is being used incorrectly.
There is no other solution than to use the [`EmailAddressAttribute`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs) and [`PhoneAttribute`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/PhoneAttribute.cs) as demonstrated below in the following example.

```
[Phone]
[Display(Name = "Phone #")]
public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

[Phone]
[Display(Name = "Fax #")]
public string FaxNo { get; set; }

[EmailAddress]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Those attribute are derived from `DataTypeAttribute` and overrides the `IsValid` method which is what checks that the value is in fact valid.