# How to restrict text box to allow only numbers and format as US mobile number format in react js?

Tags: reactjs

How to restrict textbox to allow only numbers and format as US mobile number format in react js ? ex : (456) 125-0156. Below code to allow only numbers.

```
mobileNumberChange(evt) {
    var decimalvalidate = /^[2-9][0-9]*$/;
    if (!decimalvalidate.test(evt.key)) {
      evt.preventDefault();
}
```

But how will I format as (456) 125-0156 ?

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, you're looking for a regexp to validate US phone numbers, which will be

`/^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/`

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776231/regular-expression-to-validate-us-phone-numbers) answer for detailed explanation