# Add another function to current JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

Can someone please tell me how to add my below JavaScript (function validateEmail() to the JavaScript I already created (function validateForm()?  I need to combine the 2 into one.  What I did was create a JavaScript to create error messages, then my new one creates an error message if the Email field was typed incorrectly.  The longer JavaScript is what needs the shorter one.  Do I just add an else if, if than?  I am new to JavaScript.  Thank you for those that help.

```
function validateForm() {
    var ret = true;
    var name = document.forms["contactform"]["name"].value;
    var nameError = document.getElementById('name.error');
    if (name == "") {
        nameError.innerHTML = "Please enter your name";
        ret = false;
    } 
    else {
        nameError.innerHTML = "";
    }
    var email = document.forms["contactform"]["email"].value;
    var emailError = document.getElementById('email.error');
    if (email == "") {
        emailError.innerHTML = "Please enter your Email";
        ret = false;
    } 
    else {
        emailError.innerHTML = "";
    }
    var phone = document.forms["contactform"]["telephone"].value;
    var phoneError = document.getElementById('telephone.error');
    if (phone == "") {
        phoneError.innerHTML = "Please enter your telephone";
        ret = false;
    }
    else {
        phoneError.innerHTML = "";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

NEW JAVASCRIPT

```
function validateEmail() {
    var email = document.forms["contactform"]["email"].value;
    var emailError = document.getElementById('email.error');
    var valid = /[^@]+@[^@]+/.test(email);
    if (!valid) {
        emailError.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address";
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: I don't care which [indent style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) you pick, as long as you *do* pick one...

Comment: Is the additional function in a separate file?

Comment: Yes.  I created a file called test.js and it actually worked, so now I need to add it to the one that creates error messages.

Comment: @nnnnnn I can’t guarantee the correctness of the code, but now it looks nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final function should look like below:

```
function validateForm() {
  var ret = true;
  var name = document.forms["contactform"]["name"].value;
  var nameError = document.getElementById('name.error');
  if (name == "") {
    nameError.innerHTML = "Please enter your name";
    ret = false;
  } 
  else {
    nameError.innerHTML = "";
  }

  ret &= validateEmail();

  var phone = document.forms["contactform"]["telephone"].value;
  var phoneError = document.getElementById('telephone.error');
  if (phone == "") {
    phoneError.innerHTML = "Please enter your telephone";
    ret = false;
  }
  else {
    phoneError.innerHTML = "";
  }
  return ret;
}

// in diff file
function validateEmail() {
  var email = document.forms["contactform"]["email"].value;
  var emailError = document.getElementById('email.error');
  var valid = /[^@]+@[^@]+/.test(email);
  if (!valid) {
    emailError.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address";
  }
   else {
    emailError.innerHTML = "";
   }
  return valid;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you can not (or dont want to) change `validateForm` function to include call to `validateEmail` then you can specify both functions in the form `onsubmit`

```
onsubmit="return validateForm() && validateEmail()"
```

Comment: Do I type the rest of the code below ret &= validateEmail();?

Comment: I see now.  Am about to test in one min.  But first, can you tell me what ret &= validateEmail(); means???  Thank you.

Comment: It assign the value returned from the `validateEmail` function to the `ret` variabe in the [bitwise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) fashion.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what about my code for the error message for the Email?

Comment: It is (should be) combined in the `validateEmail` function. If you can not combine them then just call the `validateEmail` from the `validateForm`

Comment: I can have this: <form action="form.php" method="post" name="contactform" onsubmit="return validateForm()"
onsubmit="return validateEmail()">

Comment: I'm sorry, but it does not work. <form action="form.php" method="post" name="contactform" onsubmit="return validateForm() && return validateEmail()">

Comment: Please notice that you have two `return` statements. It should be only one. See **EDIT** in my asnwer

Comment: Amazing.  It works.  Thank you so much.  This has taken me many hours today.  Can you guide me in the right direction on how to validate a phone number?  Jon Duckett's book does not describe that.

Comment: Glad I could helpand welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the phone number validation criteria?

Comment: Thank you.  I am only 1 week into JavaScript.  Just a normal phone number- 1112223333.  What are the criteria I can choose from?

Comment: It could be international phone, or North America phone (10 digit). The validation would be similiar to email but with different [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9776231/4454454)

Comment: I will look into this 'regex' I see all over the place.  In my onsubmit area where you helped me, do I just add another '&'?  onsubmit="return validateForm() && validateEmail() &&& validatePhone() &&&& validateName()"

Comment: You can do that (with two `&&`) but it really should be a part of the form validation code. So I would advise to add it there and have only one function for `onsubmit`

Comment: If you have time, don't have to tonight, can you show me how to add it into one code?

Answer (score 0):

Your form validation script simply needs to call your additional function as an additional test.

Try adding this to the end of your main function:

```
if(!validateEmail()) {
    //  error code
    ret=false;
}
else {
    //  ok
}

return ret;
```

Comment: But my form action has onsubmit="return validateForm()"

Comment: Where do I add another form action onsubmit?

Comment: @t_strudel Sorry, I completely misunderstood the question. I have changed the answer accordingly.