# How do I set a regexp with optional "(" and ")" that requires both when used?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a reg expression that validates US phone numbers.  The country code is optional as well as parenthesis around the area code.  So far I have this

```
/^[1]?[-. ]?\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/
```

it works, however it will allow submissions like

> 1 555) 555 5555

and

> 1 (555 555 5555

I need to somehow tell the expression that `()` are optional but if a user uses one they have to close it off properly as well.  How this could be done?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/9776278/4040563

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to work with branches:

```
^1?[-. ]?(?:\((\d{3})\)|(\d{3}))[-. ]?(\d{3})[-. ]?(\d{4})$
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

First side of alternation goes with a pair of parentheses and the other side with digits only. This way it doesn't allow unbalanced parentheses to take place.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/4KFtnF/1)