# SQL - Remove a certain part of an array in a column with a array data type

Tags: sql

I have a contacts column which has, an id and sms (array) columns. 
I would like to remove all non US numbers (all numbers that starts with 1) And I am not quite sure how to do this.

I am not sure if it would be appropriate to do a FOR LOOP for this query or should I do a simple query? Is there any way to do this query?

Comment: Showing a basic attempt with code will get you further

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to do it on an SQL query:
Assuming column where you store all the phone numbers: to be like `phone`
You could use a query like this:

`SELECT * FROM sms WHERE phone NOT LIKE '+1%' AND phone NOT LIKE '1%' AND phone NOT LIKE '001%' AND phone NOT LIKE '01%'`

And If you decided to do it on code, you could use a regular expression instead:

[RegEx to Validate US numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776231/regular-expression-to-validate-us-phone-numbers)

In think If you give us more information, we could be able to help you in a better way.
Regards,