# How to validate a german telephone number using javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

In an application i need to validate a form field for german telephone numbers,tried some but doesnt works exactly, any help will be appreciated..

Comment: What does a German telephone number look like?

Comment: is the number comprehensive of the +(intl prefix) ?

Comment: i guess you want to check if the area code exists? or what exactly do you want to check? Just my opinion: dont do it anyway, or have you ever seen ANY form that actually checks if a telephone number is correct / plausible?

Comment: is the number check is enough for a telephone number field?

Comment: I think this is the format?
 
1. " nnn - nnn nn nn " in case of Big Cities.
2. " nnnn - nn nn nn " in case of Small Towns.
 
For Zwolle (Big Cities) : 038 - 123 45 67
For xyzTown(Small Cities/Town) : 0381 - 12 34 56

Comment: Checking if an areacode exists is not really possible. The following telephone numbers are all valid an equal:
"+49 (0)371 111222"
"+49 371 111222"
"0371 111222"
"0371111222"
"(0371) 111222".
There are more combinations possible.

Answer (score 10):

The answers to this question should solve this for you: [Validate phone number with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4338267/669645)

You just need to adjust the regex to suit the German format

The regex from https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/issues/265 might do the job:
/^([+][0-9]{1,3}[ .-])?([(]{1}[0-9]{1,6}[)])?([0-9 .-/]{3,20})((x|ext|extension)[ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?$/

Comment: slightly adapted version resolving some minor issues with country code detection in combination with the actual number: `^(?:([+][0-9]{1,2})+[ .-]*)?([(]{1}[0-9]{1,6}[)])?([0-9 .-/]{3,20})((x|ext|extension)[ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?$`