# Validating phone number with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with three elements. I want to validate the phone number when the user enters it. If the user moves to the next element and phone number contains and characters which is not numbers I want to display an alertbox.

I have written some code but am completely stumped. The problem I am having with my function is, that even if I enter only numbers into the phone number element I still get the alert box displayed. My code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
checkNr= isNaN(document.forms[0].elements[1])
if(checkNr == true)
{
window.alert("You can only enter numbers. Please try again")
}
} 
</script>

<form>
  <strong>FULLNAME: </strong><input type="text" / id="name"><br />
  <strong>PHONE NR: </strong><input type="text" id="phone"  onblur="validateForm()" />
  <strong>NATIONALITY</strong><input type="text" id="nat" /><br />
  <input type="button" id="subButton" onclick="calc()" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Thank you in advance for all your answers and help.

Comment: Try alerting `document.forms[0].elements[1]` itself to see if the value is what you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
document.forms[0].elements[1]
```

to

```
document.forms[0].elements[1].value
```

You were testing the element itself, not the element's value.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Fd4uR/)**

BTW, if someone enters a phone number with a dash or parenthesis (e.g. (555) 123-4567) what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Thank you for very much for you clear answer. It worked great. To be honest I have not thought about what would happen if someone puts in a dash. From reading some of the responses I can see that some patterns will need to be used. Unfortunately I dont understand the code...

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phone-no-validation.php) you will find many exemple to achieve your goal :

for example if you can use only number :

```
function phonenumber(inputtxt)  
{  
  var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
  if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))  
        {  
      return true;  
        }  
      else  
        {  
        alert("message");  
        return false;  
        }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with a regular expression. See here:

[A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

[Validate phone number with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338267/validate-phone-number-with-javascript)