# Phone validation custom Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

Am using jQuery to validate my form. How can I create a custom phone validation regular expression so that I can validate my phone field to accept numbers with hyphen and not in any particular order it may be 33333-23232, or 343-3434-343434, or  in any form but it must have **only numeric and hyphen**.

I have tested with this `var intRegex = /^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;` but this is will be for a particular order like 999-999-9999.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. It's a simple JavaScript problem. jQuery may be popular, but people need to learn that it's a library that adds functionality on top of JavaScript. A JavaScript problem often doesn't require jQuery.

Comment: Second, you shouldn't use regular expressions to [validate phone numbers properly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4338544/1269037).

Answer (score 1):

One regular expression is `/^[\d-]+$/`, but you [should learn more about regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and play with some data in a playground like http://regex101.com.

Anyway, using a simple regular expression to validate phone numbers is naive. The following are phone numbers that users will want to be able to enter:

+1-415.123.4567

+1-408-123-MARC

(650)-123-4567

And that's U.S. alone.

There are entire [articles on validating phone numbers with regular expressions](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/validate-phone-number) and [comprehensive StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338267/validate-phone-number-with-javascript). Don't use regular expressions. Use a specialized library like [Google's liphonenumber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5059082/1269037).

Comment: It does allow digits and the hyphen. As advised, test it at http://regex101.com/r/hE7kV0

Comment: yes it (var intRegex =/^[\d-]+$/;) allows these  types of format 1.only numbers 2.only numbers and hyphen .Any way to allow format 2 alone?

Answer (score -1):

Used  var intRegex =/^[\d-]+$/;  to check if it is only with numbers or numbers and hyphen in no particular order

Comment: The `|` in the middle of the `[]` character class doesn't do what you think :) That regexp will also match "123-456|7890". Again, my answer is correct.