# Phone Number validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

I have an application form in php.. I need to validate the phone number.. Please tel me how to validate a phone no. Here is the code..

```
$(function() {
        $("#XISubmit").click(function(){

var XIPhone= document.forms["XIForm"]["XIPhone"].value;
    if (XIPhone==null || XIPhone=="") { alert("Please Enter Office Phone No"); return false; }

document.getElementById("XIForm").submit();
        }); 


<div class="formItem">
            <label>Office Phone No</label>
            <input type="text" name="XIPhone" id="XIPhone" />
        </div>

    <div class="formItem">
            <input type="hidden" name="formType" id="formType" value="XI" />
            <input type="button" name="XISubmit" id="XISubmit" value="Submit"          class="formButton" />
        </div>

        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: Depends on the phone number format (country).

Comment: With some special format? You must write a phone number?.... Tell your cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate phone number with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338267/validate-phone-number-with-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some regular expression formats :

```
Phone Number (Format: +99(99)9999-9999) - [\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{2}[\)]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}  
UK Phone Number - ^\s*\(?(020[7,8]{1}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9{2}[ ]?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8]{1}[0-9]{3}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]{3})\s*$  
USA Phone Number -  US based Phone Number in the format of: 123-456-7890 - \d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = yourdata;
var re = /^\d{10}$/;    //user regular expression (this example is used to check 
                        // validation for 10 numbers or digits).
var a = data.match(re);
if(a == null)
{

   //show error message

}
else
{
   //no error
}
```

- Use regular expression
- Format of Phone numbers and landline numbers will change based on country

Answer (score 0):

A simple case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
      var reg = /^\d{10}$/;  
      function PhoneValidation(phoneNumber)
      {  
        return reg.test(phoneNumber);
      }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
function checkForNumber(number, size) {
    var nbrString = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        var cc = number.charCodeAt(i);
        if (cc >= 48 && cc < 58) {
            nbrString += number[i];
        }
    }
    return nbrString.length === size;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var paramA = "012 345 67 89";
var paramB = 10;
checkForNumber(paramA, paramB);
```

**paramA:** your number to check in string format

**paramB:** the size of the number digits *(normally it's 10)*

*You can modify the return parameter in the 'checkForNumber' function to fit your needs.*

**Here is an example** on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fPMRL/).