# MVC client side validation for PhoneAttribute

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, forms, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I have a model:

```
public class MyModel{
    [Phone]
    public string MyTel { get; set; }
}
```

in the view:

```
@model MyModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyTel)
```

the HTML generated:

```
<input type="tel" value="" name="MyTel" id="MyTel" data-val-phone="The MyTel field is not a valid phone number." data-val="true" class="text-box single-line"/>
```

the client side validation for the MyTel field does not working. How to make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Guided by article [Adding Client-Side Validation Support for PhoneAttribute or Fighting the Lookbehind in JavaScript](http://amanek.com/adding-client-side-validation-support-for-phoneattribute-or-fighting-the-look-behind-in-javascript/)

```
function initPhoneValidator() {
    $.validator.addMethod("phone", function (value, element) {
        if (this.optional(element)) {
            return true;
        }
        var reverseValue = $.trim(value).split("").reverse().join("");
        var reverseRegEx = new RegExp("^(\\d+\\s?(x|\\.txe?)\\s?)?((\\)(\\d+[\\s\\-\\.]?)?\\d+\\(|\\d+)[\\s\\-\\.]?)*(\\)([\\s\\-\\.]?\\d+)?\\d+\\+?\\((?!\\+.*)|\\d+)(\\s?\\+)?$", "i");
        var match = reverseRegEx.exec(reverseValue);
        return (match && (match.index === 0) && (match[0].length === value.length));
    });
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("phone");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. One comment: I don't think the `if (this.optional(...))` check should be here. If it's required, there should also be a `[Required]` attribute on the property. The way this code is now, validation will never occur for a non-required property, which is most likely not what one would expect. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: This regex does not work correctly. For example, `123` passes this test when it shouldn't. I ended up combining your solution with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4338631/374198

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I applied in my project for PhoneAttribute :

**Step 1:** add these annotations

```
public class MyModel{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must provide a mobile number")]
    [Phone]
    [MaxLength(13)] //custom maximum length enabled
    [MinLength(10)]//custom minimum length enabled
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "mobile number must be 
    numeric")]
    public string MyTel { get; set; }
}
```

**Step 2:** add these two libraries

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

**Step 3:** In Web.config under appSettings add

```
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

NB: Don't mix up mvc html helper and raw html it may disable client-side validation.