# Phone validate regex

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to make a regular expression on validating phone numbers to start with 02 and be 10 digits(including the 02). This is what I have but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
/^02[0-9]{8}$/
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate phone number with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338267/validate-phone-number-with-javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338267/validate-phone-number-with-javascript

Comment: You should at least have given some sample phone numbers you are trying to match.

Comment: This regex is okay, it takes `02XXXXXXXX`, of course, with no other characters like space, etc.

Comment: Please provide some examples of numbers that fail to validate with your regexp.

Comment: example of fail: 9999999999, 8888888888, 0123456789

Comment: @JeromyTjaardstra These do fail because they don't start with 02, as your asked for. Please provide examples of numbers which don't act as you expect.

Comment: can you post the code where you are using this regex?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If I use the phone number 0234567891, a possible regex could be:

```
/^(02){1}[0-9]{8}$/
```

Ensure you match the '02' exactly once and then and 8 digits after.

Comment: This will match patterns inside phone numbers longer than 10 digits

Comment: @praval: you need to add anchors to the regex for perfect 10 digit match. check out http://regexr.com - very useful site.

Comment: @Harish. Thanks I've added the anchor tags.