# remove characters from form input on submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a `form` on my website with a mobile telephone number `input`.

I am using validation that allows the user to either enter:

```
a: 0 7725 878 811
b: +44 7725 878 811
```

I would like to remove the first 0 or +44 when submitting the `form` so that the value that ends up in the database is simply 7725 878 811

What would be the best way to go about this?

Different to marked as duplicate as it is not validation I have an issue with, it is with cleaning the value upon submit

Comment: What does your form currently look like? A single text field? Separate fields for each portion of the number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate phone number with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338267/validate-phone-number-with-javascript)

Comment: var phonenumber = phonenumber.substring(phonenumber.indexOf(' '));

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to attach a handler to the `submit` event of the form, changing the value there and then submitting it. With JQuery it'd be something like:

```
$("#theForm").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Modify the input value here
    // ...

    this.submit();
});
```

Comment: and with this method how would i remove either the leading 0 or +44 from the #number field?

Comment: With a regex: `value.replace(/^(0|\+44) */, '');`

Answer (score 1):

When handling the form, try getting the input value and removing the 0/+44 using Regex:

```
var inputVal = $('#yourinputid').val(); //gets the input 
inputVal.replace(/^(0|\+44) */, '');//remove the 0 or +44 using regex
```

So handling your form before submit, should be something along the lines of this:

```
$("#form-id").on("submit", function(e){   
     e.preventDefault();

     //gets the input
     var inputVal = $('#yourinput-id').val(); 

     //remove the 0 or +44 using regex
     inputVal.replace(/^(0|\+44) */, '');

     //re-set input value to your new value without 0 and +44
     $('#yourinput-id').val(inputVal); 

      //write your other code

      //then submit your form
      this.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace `0` or `+ any 2 digits` you can simply use below method:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Lpkryh93/)**

```
var value=$('#yourcontrolid').val();
value=value.replace(/^(0|\+\d\d) */, '')
```

`value` will have newly fetched value which you can send and store in DB. The above `regex` will replace `0` or `+44`,`+91` etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is only with 0 and +44?

I would put a mask on the field to force the user to type the region code, and after that treat the result.

You can either split the string by space (' '), or something like that, and remove the first ocurrency, or use regex (like already answered) but remove the plus sign and first two digits.

For instance:

```
value.replace(/^(0|\+\d\d) */, '')
```

and so on