# javascript regex : for US phone number

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

Hi I am trying to write regex but facing some issues over it. can anyone help me write one.

conditions :

•   ALL 10 digits being 0 is not allowed.
•   The area code (first 3 digits) cannot be the same digit,
•   The 1st and 4th digit cannot be 0 or 1.

```
/^\({0,1}[2-9]{1}[0-9]{2}\){1} {1}[2-9]{1}[0-9]{2}-{0,1}[0-9]{0,4}$/
```

Example format: (234) 567-7890

The above question is different than the other ones as it focuses more on a specific conditions to fulfill with regex.

Comment: can you show the format you are trying to match?

Comment: something like : (000) 234 - 5678 should be invalid.

Comment: (367) 123 - 4567 should be invalid. as 4th digit is 1, which is not allowed.

Comment: Quantifiers like `{m,n}` go *after* the expression they're quantifying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: and [Validate phone number with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338267/validate-phone-number-with-javascript)

Comment: says `ALL 9 digits being 0 is not allowed.` then shows an example - `(367) 123 - 4567` showing 10 digits

Comment: @JaromandaX `'(367) 123 - 4567'.indexOf('0') // -1` Where did you see `0` in this string?

Comment: @Vidul - there are **10** digits in the example number, but _all 9 being 0 is not allowed_  the inconsistency has nothing to do with the digit 0, it has to do with counting up to 10

Comment: @JaromandaX my guess is OP just had a brainfart and meant 10, seeing as how a valid U.S. number has 7 digits for the local number + 3 digits for the area code for a total of 10 digits

Comment: I think Mark Reed wrote exactly what you need. Have a look.

Answer (score 4):

So, first, I should point out that requiring US-formatted telephone numbers is pretty restrictive; international numbers can have very different rules.  That said, this regex should meet your needs:

```
/(?:^|\D)\(([2-9])(?:\d(?!\1)\d|(?!\1)\d\d)\)\s*[2-9]\d{2}-\d{4}/
```

First,to prevent matching things that end with a valid phone number but have extra junk up front, we match either the start of the string (`^`) or a non-digit (`\D`). Then the opening parenthesis of the area code, (`\(`).

Then we match the first digit of the area code, `[2-9]`.

Then we match *either* any digit (`\d`) followed by any digit *except* the first one (`(?!\1)\d`), *or* the other way around (`(?!\1)\d\d`).  This keeps the area code from being three identical digits.

Then we close the parens (`\)`), allow (but don't require) space (`\s*`) before the first digit of the prefix (`[2-9]` again), followed by any two digits (`\d{2}`), a hyphen, and any four digits (`\d{4}`).

Comment: that sound's correct solution to me let me test it out. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go by parts, you got three conditions:

1. ALL 9 digits being 0 is not allowed
2. The area code (first 3 digits) cannot be the same digit,
3. The 1st and 4th digit cannot be 0 or 1.

Condition 1 is redundant if you consider condition 3; A simple regex not considering condition 2 is:

```
/^\([2-9]\d\d\) [2-9]\d\d-\d{4}$/
```

Assuming you want parenthesis and spaces - (555) 555-5555

Explanation:

- \d  matches any digit
- [2-9] matches any character from 2 to 9
- space and dash are literals - match spaces and dash
- {4} is a quantifier - will match 4 digits in this case
- ( and ) are escaped literals - will match ( and ) respectively

Now if we want to consider condition number 2 in our expression, we use

- a negative lookahead ?!
- a capturing group () and
- a back reference \1.

Read some regex reference if you want to fully understand those. The full expression is:

```
^\(([2-9])(?!\1\1)\d\d\) [2-9]\d\d-\d{4}$
```

Comment: first of all thanks a ton for your efforts. I can see proper logic out of your solution. I will wait for complete answer. thanks again.

Comment: I just made some changes. Now the answer is complete

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\D([2-9])(?!\1\1)\d{2}\D\s+[2-9]\d{2}\s+\W\s+\d{4}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `input` attribute `maxlength` to `10` , utilizing `Array.prototype.map` , `Array.prototype.every`

```js
/*
• ALL 9 digits being 0 is not allowed.
• The area code (first 3 digits) cannot be the same digit,
• The 1st and 4th digit cannot be 0 or 1.
*/
document.querySelector("input").oninput = function(e) {
  var vals = this.value.split("");
  if (vals.length === 10) {
    var all = vals.map(Number).every(function(n) {
      return n === 0
    })
    , area = vals.map(Number).slice(1, 3).every(function(n) {
      return n === Number(vals[0]);
    })
    , numbers = (Number(vals[0]) === (0 || 1)) || (Number(vals[3]) === (0 || 1))
    , res = all === area === numbers;
    if (!!res) {
      alert("invalid entry")
    } else {
      alert(vals.join(""))
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="10" />
```

Comment: the logic is correct but I was more focusing on regex but I can definitely try to implement that if it works out. Thanks for your efforts.