# how to validate specific phone number using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, preg-match

I have a specific format of phone number such as

> USA (+1) 000-000-0000

And I want to write a regex for this one. country code can be change but rest of the format should be same all the time. please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate phone number with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338267/validate-phone-number-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REGEX in order to define a pattern,
`/^\w+ \(\+\d+\) \d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}$/` will do the trick.

```js
const pones = [
  'USA (+1) 000-000-0000',
  'USA (+12) 123-123-5656',
  'OTHERCOUNTRY (+1) 000-000-0000',
  'USA (+1) 1000-000-0000',
  'USA (+1) 000-1000-0000',
  'USA (+1) 000-000-10000',
];
const phoneRegex = /^\w+ \(\+\d+\) \d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}$/

console.log(pones.map(phone => phoneRegex.test(phone)))
```

Comment: It is not necessary that country could be USA only.. it could be any country

Comment: Updated the example

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
function validatePhone(num) {
    var re = /\b\d{3}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}\b/g;
    return re.test(num);
}
```

You might wanna build or check your own regex. based upon your format