# regex to allow + only at the begining

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex to validate phone numbers. It should allow only `+` , `(`, `)` and `-` symbol in it. Right now everything works fine except for 2 issues. The regex should allow `+` symbol only at the beginning and not anywhere in the middle.
the other symbols, ie: `-`, `(` and `)` symbols should not appear one after another.

regex used is as follows

```
/^(?=.*?[1-9])[0-9-()+ ]+$/
```

any suggestions to fix this would be helpful.

Comment: Remove `+` & `-` from character class and add them after `^` anchor inside character class. Follow it by `?` to make it optional.

Comment: Can you show us some sample numbers which you are trying to match?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate phone number with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338267/validate-phone-number-with-javascript)

Comment: To save you some time, the accepted answer on that question says: Don't use a regex, use a library, and [this](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) is the library they linked.

Answer (score 0):

This code will only allow you to enter + and - at the beginning.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Modifiers</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" name="mob" id="demo">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="myfunc()">

    <script type="text/javascript">

function myfunc(){
    var movV= document.getElementById('demo').value; 
    var mob = movV.replace(/[?:+ | ?:-]\d/, '');
    if (mob != movV) {
        alert("true");
    } 
    else if (mob == movV) {
        alert("false");
    }
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you state that right now everything works fine except for 2 issues, you could allow an optional plus sign at the beginning of the string:

`\+?`

If you mean by

> "the other symbols, ie: `-`, `(` and `)` symbols should not appear
>   one after another"

that `((` or `)))` or `----` should not happen, then you could use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that the `-`, `(` and `)` symbols should not appear one after another:

`(?!.*([-()])(?=\1))`

**Explanation**

- A negative lookahead `(?!`
- Which asserts that what follows `.*`
- Capture in a group the possible symbols `([-()])`
- A positive lookahead `(?=`
- Which asserts that what follows is what is captured in group 1 `\1`
- Close the positive lookahead `)`
- Close the negative lookahead `)`

Your regex would then look like:

`^\+?(?!.*([-()])(?=\1))(?=.*?[1-9])[0-9-()+ ]+$`