# Validate phone number in javascript using regular expression with same functionality like keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Validate phone number in javascript using regular expression with same functionality like keypress

```
$('#phone').keypress(function(e) {
                var a = [];
                var k = e.which;

                for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
                    a.push(i);

                if (!(a.indexOf(k)>=0))
                    e.preventDefault();
            });
```

Comment: What even is the question here? Is this even a question? I see a statement and some code. No indication what the intention is, if anything is going wrong, what is expected.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate phone number with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338267/validate-phone-number-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick, working example. **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vu4hkxde/1/)**

```
<style>
    .invalid {
        border: 2px solid red; 
    }
</style>

<input id="input" type="text" />

<script>
    // save reference to input
    const input = $('#input');

    // save regex to check against
    const regex = new RegExp('^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$', 'im');

    // on keypress, get user input
    // strip non-digits (1-2 => 12 | 5.6 => 56)
    // run regex test and add/remove class to show validation
    function checkPhoneNumber(){
        const user_input = input.val().replace(/\D/g, ""); // replace any non-digits with nothing
        const valid_phone = regex.test(user_input);
        if (valid_phone){
            input.removeClass('invalid');
        } else {
            input.addClass('invalid');
        }
    }

    // attach listener with function
    input.on('keyup', checkPhoneNumber);
</script>
```

Comment: export const simpleAction = (filterData)=>{
const url ='https://reqres.in/api/users';
return function (dispatch) {
fetch(url)
  .then(function(resp) {
   return resp.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
     let dt=data.data;
     if(filterData !==''){
   dt= data.data.filter(val=>val.first_name==filterData);
     }
   dispatch({
    type: 'SIMPLE_ACTION',
    payload: dt
   })
    });
 }
}

Comment: export const Details = (data) => {
  
  const dt= data.data;
  let  namesList ='';
  if(dt[0] !== undefined){
    if(dt!== undefined){
   namesList = dt.map(dt=>(<li key={dt.id} className='boxItem' onClick={() => {
            onItemClick();
          }}>
          {dt.first_name}
          </li>
                      ));
  }
}
      return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                {namesList}
            </ul>
        </div>
            );
};