# Need help for form and data validation please

Tags: javascript, html

starting learning java html programming and need a bit of help for data validation in html forms.

Can anybody help out on the email pattern and the phone number data validation pls? Thanks heaps

```
// validating email pattern with @gmail.com

if (email.value.indexOf("@", 0) < 0) {
window.alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address.")
email.focus();
return false;
}

//validating phone number

if (phone.value =="//needs to be numbers only" ) {
window.alert("Please enter a valid phone number.")
phone.focus();
return false; }
```

Any assistance with email pattern and number validation would be great.

Comment: you mean javascript, not java, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Both of your problems are already asked here. You can find them by simply searching. or example take a look at these links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338267/validate-phone-number-with-javascript) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

don't mistake Java for JavaScript ! They're way not the same in use context, process or writing....
You can use HTML attributes such 
`<input type="number">` to more and better checking(but that won't replace a check in the code) and/or attributes range , required.
For string checks and finer checks you'll have to use regular expressions.