# validate phone number in format (123) 456-7891

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I want to validate a phone number and am using the following regex, although it isn't working.

```js
function validPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
  const pattern = /^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/
  return pattern.test(phoneNumber);
}

console.log(validPhoneNumber("(123) 456-7890")); //should return true
console.log(validPhoneNumber("(1111)555 2345")); // should return false
console.log(validPhoneNumber("(098) 123 4567")); // should return false
```

Comment: What about other format variants? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4338544/924299) might be informative.

Comment: Any reasons why you use `(\()?` instead of `\(?` and `(-|\s)` instead of `[\s-]`?

Answer (score 2):

Just removed the `?` **(indicates zero or one occurrences)** and `\s` **(to allow only `-`)**

```js
function validPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
  const pattern = /^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)\d{3}(-)\d{4}$/
  //                                    ^^    ^^^
  return pattern.test(phoneNumber);
}


console.log(validPhoneNumber("(123) 456-7890"))
console.log(validPhoneNumber("(123)-456-7890"))
console.log(validPhoneNumber("(123)456-7890"))
console.log(validPhoneNumber("(1111)555 2345"))
console.log(validPhoneNumber("(098) 123 4567"))
```

Comment: this fails if I do something like `abc(123)456-7890`

Comment: @peterflanagan fixed. post all test case in question

Comment: will mark as accepted answer when I can

Answer (score 0):

Check This

```
function validPhoneNumber(phoneNumber){
    const pattern =  /^(\()?\d{3}(\))\s{0,1}(-|\s)?\d{3}-\d{4}$/
    return pattern.test(phoneNumber);
}

validPhoneNumber("(123) 456-7890")  =>  should return true
validPhoneNumber("(1111)555 2345")  => should return false
validPhoneNumber("(098) 123 4567")  => should return false
```