# How To Get TimeZone By Area Code In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timezone

I have Area Codes Of The User.

Is it Possible By A Script To Get Time Zone By Area Code In JavaScript ?

Comment: You could just find a list online e.g. https://greatdata.com/proddata/info/areacodetimezone and build a map of area code to timezone.

Comment: It is not possible - in any language.  Area codes can cover more than one time zone, and people can take their phone numbers with them when they move to other areas, on both mobile and land-lines.  See the linked duplicate for examples.

Answer (score 0):

I just grabbed the info from this page and built a look-up map:

> https://greatdata.com/proddata/info/areacodetimezone

```js
const timeZoneMap = getTimeZoneMap()
// See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33561517/1762224
const phoneNumberPattern = /^[+]*[(]{0,1}\d{1,3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$/g

console.log(timeZoneMap[extractAreaCode('(619) 555-5555')]) // California (PST)

function extractAreaCode(phoneNumber) {
  if (phoneNumberPattern.test(phoneNumber)) {
    return /\d{3}/.exec(phoneNumber)[0] // first three sequential
  }
  return null
}

function getTimeZoneMap() {
  return {
    "201" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New Jersey" },
    "202" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "District of Columbia" },
    "203" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Connecticut" },
    "205" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Alabama" },
    "206" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "Washington" },
    "207" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Maine" },
    "208" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Idaho" },
    "209" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "210" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "212" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "213" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "214" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "215" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Pennsylvania" },
    "216" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Ohio" },
    "217" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Illinois" },
    "218" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Minnesota" },
    "219" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Indiana" },
    "220" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Ohio" },
    "224" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Illinois" },
    "225" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Louisiana" },
    "228" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Mississippi" },
    "229" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Georgia" },
    "231" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Michigan" },
    "234" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Ohio" },
    "239" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "240" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Maryland" },
    "248" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Michigan" },
    "251" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Alabama" },
    "252" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "North Carolina" },
    "253" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "Washington" },
    "254" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "256" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Alabama" },
    "260" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Indiana" },
    "262" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Wisconsin" },
    "267" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Pennsylvania" },
    "269" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Michigan" },
    "270" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Kentucky" },
    "272" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Pennsylvania" },
    "276" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Virginia" },
    "281" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "301" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Maryland" },
    "302" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Delaware" },
    "303" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Colorado" },
    "304" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "West Virginia" },
    "305" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "307" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Wyoming" },
    "308" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Nebraska" },
    "309" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Illinois" },
    "310" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "312" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Illinois" },
    "313" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Michigan" },
    "314" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Missouri" },
    "315" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "316" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Kansas" },
    "317" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Indiana" },
    "318" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Louisiana" },
    "319" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Iowa" },
    "320" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Minnesota" },
    "321" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "323" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "325" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "330" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Ohio" },
    "331" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Illinois" },
    "332" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "334" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Alabama" },
    "336" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "North Carolina" },
    "337" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Louisiana" },
    "339" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Massachusetts" },
    "346" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "347" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "351" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Massachusetts" },
    "352" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "360" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "Washington" },
    "361" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "364" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Kentucky" },
    "380" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Ohio" },
    "385" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Utah" },
    "386" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "401" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Rhode Island" },
    "402" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Nebraska" },
    "404" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Georgia" },
    "405" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Oklahoma" },
    "406" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Montana" },
    "407" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "408" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "409" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "410" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Maryland" },
    "412" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Pennsylvania" },
    "413" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Massachusetts" },
    "414" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Wisconsin" },
    "415" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "417" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Missouri" },
    "419" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Ohio" },
    "423" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Tennessee" },
    "424" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "425" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "Washington" },
    "430" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "432" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "434" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Virginia" },
    "435" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Utah" },
    "440" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Ohio" },
    "442" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "443" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Maryland" },
    "456" : null,
    "458" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "Oregon" },
    "463" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Indiana" },
    "469" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "470" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Georgia" },
    "475" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Connecticut" },
    "478" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Georgia" },
    "479" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Arkansas" },
    "480" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Arizona" },
    "484" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Pennsylvania" },
    "500" : null,
    "501" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Arkansas" },
    "502" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Kentucky" },
    "503" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "Oregon" },
    "504" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Louisiana" },
    "505" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "New Mexico" },
    "507" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Minnesota" },
    "508" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Massachusetts" },
    "509" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "Washington" },
    "510" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "512" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "513" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Ohio" },
    "515" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Iowa" },
    "516" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "517" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Michigan" },
    "518" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "520" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Arizona" },
    "522" : null,
    "530" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "531" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Nebraska" },
    "533" : null,
    "534" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Wisconsin" },
    "539" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Oklahoma" },
    "540" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Virginia" },
    "541" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "Oregon" },
    "544" : null,
    "551" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New Jersey" },
    "559" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "561" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "562" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "563" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Iowa" },
    "566" : null,
    "567" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Ohio" },
    "570" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Pennsylvania" },
    "571" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Virginia" },
    "573" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Missouri" },
    "574" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Indiana" },
    "575" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "New Mexico" },
    "580" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Oklahoma" },
    "585" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "586" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Michigan" },
    "588" : null,
    "601" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Mississippi" },
    "602" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Arizona" },
    "603" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New Hampshire" },
    "605" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "South Dakota" },
    "606" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Kentucky" },
    "607" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "608" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Wisconsin" },
    "609" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New Jersey" },
    "610" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Pennsylvania" },
    "611" : null,
    "612" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Minnesota" },
    "614" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Ohio" },
    "615" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Tennessee" },
    "616" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Michigan" },
    "617" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Massachusetts" },
    "618" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Illinois" },
    "619" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "620" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Kansas" },
    "623" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Arizona" },
    "626" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "628" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "629" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Tennessee" },
    "630" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Illinois" },
    "631" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "636" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Missouri" },
    "641" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Iowa" },
    "646" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "650" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "651" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Minnesota" },
    "657" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "660" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Missouri" },
    "661" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "662" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Mississippi" },
    "667" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Maryland" },
    "669" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "678" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Georgia" },
    "680" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "681" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "West Virginia" },
    "682" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "700" : null,
    "701" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "North Dakota" },
    "702" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "Nevada" },
    "703" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Virginia" },
    "704" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "North Carolina" },
    "706" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Georgia" },
    "707" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "708" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Illinois" },
    "710" : null,
    "712" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Iowa" },
    "713" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "714" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "715" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Wisconsin" },
    "716" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "717" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Pennsylvania" },
    "718" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "719" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Colorado" },
    "720" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Colorado" },
    "724" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Pennsylvania" },
    "725" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "Nevada" },
    "727" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "731" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Tennessee" },
    "732" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New Jersey" },
    "734" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Michigan" },
    "737" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "740" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Ohio" },
    "743" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "North Carolina" },
    "747" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "754" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "757" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Virginia" },
    "760" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "762" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Georgia" },
    "763" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Minnesota" },
    "765" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Indiana" },
    "769" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Mississippi" },
    "770" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Georgia" },
    "772" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "773" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Illinois" },
    "774" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Massachusetts" },
    "775" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "Nevada" },
    "779" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Illinois" },
    "781" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Massachusetts" },
    "785" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Kansas" },
    "786" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "800" : null,
    "801" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Utah" },
    "802" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Vermont" },
    "803" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "South Carolina" },
    "804" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Virginia" },
    "805" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "806" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "808" : { "timezone" : "HAST", "state" : "Hawaii" },
    "809" : { "timezone" : "AST" },
    "810" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Michigan" },
    "812" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Indiana" },
    "813" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "814" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Pennsylvania" },
    "815" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Illinois" },
    "816" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Missouri" },
    "817" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "818" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "828" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "North Carolina" },
    "830" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "831" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "832" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "833" : null,
    "843" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "South Carolina" },
    "844" : null,
    "845" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "847" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Illinois" },
    "848" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New Jersey" },
    "850" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "854" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "South Carolina" },
    "855" : null,
    "856" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New Jersey" },
    "857" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Massachusetts" },
    "858" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "859" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Kentucky" },
    "860" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Connecticut" },
    "862" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New Jersey" },
    "863" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "864" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "South Carolina" },
    "865" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Tennessee" },
    "866" : null,
    "870" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Arkansas" },
    "872" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Illinois" },
    "877" : null,
    "878" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Pennsylvania" },
    "880" : null,
    "881" : null,
    "888" : null,
    "900" : null,
    "901" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Tennessee" },
    "903" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "904" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "906" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Michigan" },
    "907" : { "timezone" : "AKST", "state" : "Alaska" },
    "908" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New Jersey" },
    "909" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "910" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "North Carolina" },
    "912" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Georgia" },
    "913" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Kansas" },
    "914" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "915" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "916" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "917" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "918" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Oklahoma" },
    "919" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "North Carolina" },
    "920" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Wisconsin" },
    "925" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "928" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Arizona" },
    "929" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "930" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Indiana" },
    "931" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Tennessee" },
    "934" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New York" },
    "936" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "937" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Ohio" },
    "938" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Alabama" },
    "940" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "941" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "947" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Michigan" },
    "949" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "951" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "California" },
    "952" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Minnesota" },
    "954" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Florida" },
    "956" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "959" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Connecticut" },
    "970" : { "timezone" : "MST", "state" : "Colorado" },
    "971" : { "timezone" : "PST", "state" : "Oregon" },
    "972" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "973" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "New Jersey" },
    "978" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Massachusetts" },
    "979" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Texas" },
    "980" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "North Carolina" },
    "984" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "North Carolina" },
    "985" : { "timezone" : "CST", "state" : "Louisiana" },
    "989" : { "timezone" : "EST", "state" : "Michigan" }
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this list is invalid because many area codes cover more than one time zone, which is not represented here.  See the examples about 605 and 928 in my answer linked as duplicate.