# Regex match valid Phone Number

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm quite new to regex, and not sure what I'm doing wrong exactly.

I'm looking for a regex that match the following number format:

Matching requirements:

1. **Must** start with either 0 or 3
2. **Must** be between 7 to 11 digits
3. **Must not** allow ascending digits. e.g. 0123456789, 01234567
4. **Must not** allow repeated digits. e.g. 011111111, 3333333333, 0000000000

This is what I came up with:

```
^(?=(^[0,3]{1}))(?!.*(\d)\1{3,})(?!^(?:0(?=1|$))?(?:1(?=2|$))?(?:2(?=3|$))?(?:3(?=4|$))?(?:4(?=5|$))?(?:5(?=6|$))?(?:6(?=7|$))?(?:7(?=8|$))?(?:8(?=9|$))?9?$).{7,11}$
```

The above regex fails the No. (4) condition. Not sure why though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use regex to validate telephone numbers? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4338544/989920

Comment: Its a requirement to use regex unfortunately. The application will be used in a specific location. @evolutionxbox

Comment: I would question the requirement.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(?!.*(\d)\1)(?!(?:0(?=1|$))?(?:1(?=2|$))?(?:2(?=3|$))?(?:3(?=4|$))?(?:4(?=5|$))?(?:5(?=6|$))?(?:6(?=7|$))?(?:7(?=8|$))?(?:8(?=9|$))?9?$)[03]\d{6,10}$`  https://regex101.com/r/4EWkQJ/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Unfortunately, it doesnt match the following case: `022682673`

Comment: @JOJO You could add a quantifier `{3}` to repeat the backreference to assert not 4 times the same char https://regex101.com/r/MWPzfO/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few notes about the pattern that you tried

- You can omit the `{1}` and the comma in `[0,3]`
- In the lookahead `(?!.*(\d)\1{3,})` the `(\d)` is the second capturing group because this `(?=(^[0,3]{1}))` contains the first capturing group so it should be `\2` instead of `\1`
- In the lookahead, you can omit the comma in `{3,}`
- In the match itself you use `.{7,11}` where the dot would match any character except a newline. You could use `\d` instead to match only digits

You pattern might look like

```
^(?=(^[03]))(?!.*(\d)\2{3})(?!^(?:0(?=1|$))?(?:1(?=2|$))?(?:2(?=3|$))?(?:3(?=4|$))?(?:4(?=5|$))?(?:5(?=6|$))?(?:6(?=7|$))?(?:7(?=8|$))?(?:8(?=9|$))?9?$)\d{7,11}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kS4QuH/1)

Or leaving out the first lookahead and move that to the match, changing the quantifier to `\d{6,10}` and repeating capture group `\1` instead of `\2`

```
^(?!.*(\d)\1{3})(?!(?:0(?=1|$))?(?:1(?=2|$))?(?:2(?=3|$))?(?:3(?=4|$))?(?:4(?=5|$))?(?:5(?=6|$))?(?:6(?=7|$))?(?:7(?=8|$))?(?:8(?=9|$))?9?$)[03]\d{6,10}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N0PKtY/1)

**Edit**

Based on the comments, the string not having 4 ascending digits:

```
^(?!.*(\d)\1{3})[03](?!\d*(?:0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789))\d{6,10}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lbCf5J/1)

Comment: I appreciate your help. However why is it accepting 023456789?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I meant is shouldnt accept ascending order

Comment: For example: it should reject if: `012345678`, `07123456`, `07271234`, `016385678`

Comment: @JOJO This will work then right? https://regex101.com/r/yhmwll/1

Comment: It won't because it only accept number starting with `02`. Remember it has to start either with 0 or 3, following by anything. But reject ascending order from any point of the number

Comment: But that also matches `07271234` where `1234` is something you don't want to allow right?

Comment: Yes, if you can improve on what I have there to reject that. Then it will be done

Comment: Because it contains `45` which should not be allowed right?

Comment: Yes, but the increase is only 45, which is only 2 numbers. It should reject if it was 073645675. i.e 4 numbers (4567)

Comment: You could extend the alternation in that case https://regex101.com/r/lbCf5J/1

Comment: So do I have to manually extend it? Can we not make the regex look out for this ascending pattern starting from anywhere until the asending reach more than 4 numbers, in which case it should reject?

Comment: I am not sure you can dot that. If there are longer ranges you could use a chacter class, but `[0-3]` is 5 chars and  `0123` is 4

Comment: Yh I see. Im accepting your answer. Really apprciate your help :)

Comment: You are welcome. will update the answer with the latest pattern and clean up some of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for a JS flavor of PCRE would be

`/^[03](?!123456(7(8(9|$)|$)|$))(?!(?<d>.)\k<d>+$)[0-9]{6,10}$/`

Explanations

1. `^[03]` starts at the beginning of the string, then reads either 0 or 3
2. `(?!123456(7(8(9|$)|$)|$))` makes sure that, after this first char, there is no sequence (if a sequence can be read, then the negative lookahead fails
3. `(?!(?<d>.)\k<d>+$)` is another negative lookahead : it ensures that the first char read (flagged *d*) is not repeated again and again until end of string
4. `[0-9]{6,10}$/` finally reads 6 to 10 digits (first one already read)

A few tests:

- "0123456789: No match"
- "01234567: No match"
- "01234568: No match"
- "011111111: No match"
- "33333333: No match"
- "333333233 is valid"
- "042157891023 is valid"
- "019856: No match"
- "0123451245 is valid"

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but why is it accepting 023456789?

Comment: Because a sequence would have been 0**1**23456789.
Without the 1 there is a jump between 0 and 2 hence it's not a sequence, is it?