# Regex for 16-digit phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a chat application where user have to fill the form before he/she begins the chat. Validation of each form field happens once user enters the value in respective form field. One of the form field is phone number and for which I wrote a regular expression as following.

```
var phoneRegex = RegExp(/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,10}$/im);
```

Regex should return 'true' for following phone numbers

- `+11234567890` - 10 digits with area code
- `1234567890` - 10 digits
- `233445678912` - 12 digits
- `2334456789122222` - 16 digits

My chat application works for first 3 numbers but doesn't work for 16 digit phone number. I am not a huge fan of regex and have limited understanding of it hence I want to to know if my regex has any fault? And if yes then how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you saying it should work for those numbers in addition to handling things like parentheses and dashes? Can you clarify your requirements a bit?

Comment: Consider a general purpose library: https://github.com/google/libphonenumber

Comment: Strongly recommend _against_ that library. It's enormous for web applications and tree-shaking does little if anything to help. It's functionally the best though.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Slbox. Admittedly I've only used the C# port in the backend.

Comment: Validation should be done server-side anyway and libphonenumber is fine for server apps. If you must do client side validation, your regex will pass on faulty input like `+(123456789`. It may be as to have a sanity check like `/^\+?[\d\(\)\s-]*$` that only allows digits, parentheses and dashes, but does not try to enforce formatting. The reason for this is all countries have differently formatted phone numbers. Trying to write a matcher for all of them is a fool's errand.

Comment: @Slbox parentheses and dashes are excluded from the requirements so the sample/test phone numbers that I proved in my question portrays all the requirements.

Comment: If you only want to match those four cases, `^(\+\d)?\d{10}(\d{2})?(\d{4})?$` Would be sufficient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate phone numbers using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex) and there's also this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338267/validate-phone-number-with-javascript

Comment: "in my question portrays all the requirements" — is the initial `+` allowed _only_ on the Ten digit number, not allowed on the Twelve or Sixteen digit numbers? Whatever the answer is, that is an _unstated_ requirement. It is unclear as currently stated, which Slbox mentions in her/his Answer below.

Comment: The questions this is marked as a duplicate of are not very "duplicate" at all - not to mention the accepted answer for one of them is to use a gigantic library that we've discussed in these comments, and that I've recommended against for most use cases, *especially front-end, which this seems to be.* OP had specific requirements that differ from those questions and I feel this should be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

#### How about this?

It checks for the optional leading '+', followed by a 16 digit number, and if that fails, it checks for any of a 10, 11, or 12 digit number.

One thing I'm not entirely clear on is if that plus is always optional though. Also I think you might mean country code instead of area code? If I'm wrong about that, then this regex is no good.

```js
^\+?(\d{16}|\d{10,12})
```

[Results on Regexr (without the leading ^, for example purposes)](https://regexr.com/5rdmp)

[image]

---

#### Alternatively you can try this

It's a bit more strict about things

```
^(\d{16}|\+?\d{11}$|\d{10,12})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your phone field is a continuous string of digits (or at least that’s what I understood from your post) why do you need to use RegExp?

Just use basic logic, something like this...

```
var N='1234567890';

var Valid=((isNaN(N)===false)&&(Number(N)>1000000000)&&(Number(N)<9999999999999999));

alert(Valid);  // test it.
```

Comment: This might be easier to understand if you don't know Regex, but this seems like madness to me.

Comment: A String of Digits is _not_ a number which you can compare with `<` and `>` -- Phone numbers in some places are allowed to have leading zeros e.g. "0001239876" which would fail the `>1000000000` test if treated as a Number, but is (could be) valid as a _phone_-number.